# Any way to set and equivalent to the CSS "text-indent" property but based on font?

Tags: css, text-indent

For some reason that escapes me, the value of "text-indent" is a number of pixels. But different fonts want different levels of indentation. I would like to avoid having to remember to set the right indentation every time I change a font, which I could do if

```
text-indent: "mmm";
```

mean "add pixels equivalent to this text in the current font." Then the text-indent would just be the same in every font. Is there anything in CSS that would achieve that effect?

Comment: Based in which sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `em` instead of `px`.

```
text-indent: 10em;
```

> The em and ex units depend on the font and may be different for each
>   element in the document. The em is simply the font size. In an element
>   with a 2in font, 1em thus means 2in. Expressing sizes, such as margins
>   and paddings, in em means they are related to the font size, and if
>   the user has a big font (e.g., on a big screen) or a small font (e.g.,
>   on a handheld device), the sizes will be in proportion. Declarations
>   such as 'text-indent: 1.5em' and 'margin: 1em' are extremely common in
>   CSS.

Reference: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units)

Comment: I probably wouldn't use "10", because that is a very wide result. But otherwise, this does work when I test it.

Comment: The `em` unit denotes the size of the font. It is independent of any other characteristics of the font. So this is the correct answer if and only if the question really means how to set the indentation as relative to font *size*.

Comment: Well, it is not correct at all unless you remove the quotes... `text-indent: "10em";` is invalid CSS and ignored by conforming browsers.